# My GLSL Diffuse Shader is not working properly. How can I fix it?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to create a GLSL diffuse shader, but I'm getting a problem, some faces looks like they become transparent and the back faces are shown in front, it's really confusing and I wonder how to fix this problem.
I guess that the problem is with the direction of the normals, but I'm not sure.

This is my .frag shader code:

```
 #version 330

 in vec3 FragPos;
 in vec3 Normals;
 in vec2 TexCoord;

 uniform vec4 AlbedoColor;

 out vec4 FragColor;

 const int numLights = 1;
 uniform vec3 lightPositions[numLights];
 uniform vec3 lightColors[numLights];
 uniform vec3 viewPos;

 uniform vec3 diffuse;

 void main()
 {
    // Perform lighting calculations here
    vec3 result = vec3(0);
    for (int i = 0; i \< numLights; i++) {
    // Diffuse
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normals);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPositionsi - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);

    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColors[i];

    result += diffuse;
    }

result = result * AlbedoColor.rgb;

FragColor = vec4(result,1.0);

}
```

If the problem is with the normals, here's the code that generates the mesh:

```
 new Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f)), // bottom-left-back

 new Vertex(-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, new Vector3(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f), new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f)), // top-left-back

 new Vertex( 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, new Vector3( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f), new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f)), // top-right-back

 new Vertex( 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, new Vector3( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f)), // bottom-right-back

 new Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f)), // bottom-left-front

 new Vertex(-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, new Vector3(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f)), // top-left-front

 new Vertex( 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, new Vector3( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f)), // top-right-front

 new Vertex( 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, new Vector3( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f))  // bottom-right-front
```

Note that the Normals direction is the second paramether. The vertex position is the first, and the third paramether is the location of the texture (it's not in use for now).

Here's some screenshots of what the current result is right now:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3KwI.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvCfW.png)

Comment: Not sure if it's your problem, but "back faces shown in front" is a common symptom of forgetting to enable depth testing.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you so much! That was the problem. I did "GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);" and it's working now! I'm new to OpenGL and don't knew that I needed to do that. Thank you so much!

Comment: the whole point of depth testing is to stop showing back faces in front, so when you forget to use it, you show back faces in front :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not enable the Depth Test.

In case someone is also with this problem, if you're using OpenGL in C#, you can do "GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);" And it's going to work fine.

Thank you @user253751 for fixing my problem!